# Encrypt with RSA - ZipException: invalid entry size

Tags: java, encryption, zip, rsa

I'm writing a program which takes as input from the console - the name of a zip file, name of a zip file to be made containig the encrypted files generate from the first zip and a file containing the public key. I get an exception every time the stream closes:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid entry size (expected 11 but got 128 bytes)
at java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream.closeEntry(ZipOutputStream.java:288)
at java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream.finish(ZipOutputStream.java:361)
at java.util.zip.DeflaterOutputStream.close(DeflaterOutputStream.java:238)
at java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream.close(ZipOutputStream.java:378)
at javax.crypto.CipherOutputStream.close(CipherOutputStream.java:217)
at com.Main.main(Main.java:107)
```

How can I fix this? The code is bellow:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.security.GeneralSecurityException;
import java.security.KeyFactory;
import java.security.PublicKey;
import java.security.spec.X509EncodedKeySpec;
import java.util.Base64;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.zip.ZipEntry;
import java.util.zip.ZipFile;
import java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream;

import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.CipherOutputStream;

public class Main {

public final static int BUFFER_SIZE = 1024;

public static String getPublicKeyString(String fileName){

    String key = new String();
    try {
        BufferedReader buf = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
        key = buf.readLine();       
    } catch ( IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }   

    return key.trim();
}

public static PublicKey makePublicKey(String stored) throws GeneralSecurityException {
    byte[] data = Base64.getDecoder().decode(stored);//Base64.decode(keyBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
    X509EncodedKeySpec spec = new  X509EncodedKeySpec(data);
    KeyFactory fact = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
    return fact.generatePublic(spec);
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter type of operation:");
    String line = scan.nextLine();

    if(line.equals("encrypt")){
        // Reading from console
        System.out.println("Enter name of original ZIP file:");
        String originalZipFileName = scan.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Enter name of new ZIP file:");
        String newZipFileName = scan.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Enter name of file containg public key:");
        String publicKeyFileName = scan.nextLine();

        String publicKey = getPublicKeyString(publicKeyFileName);

        // Declaration

        ZipFile originalZipFile = new ZipFile(originalZipFileName);

        byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];

        ZipOutputStream newZipFile = new ZipOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(newZipFileName));

        Enumeration<? extends ZipEntry> zipEntries = originalZipFile.entries();

        //

        PublicKey key = makePublicKey(publicKey);
        //System.out.println(key.toString());
        //

        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");

        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);

        while(zipEntries.hasMoreElements()){

            ZipEntry entry = zipEntries.nextElement();
            ZipEntry copy = new ZipEntry(entry);

            newZipFile.putNextEntry(copy);

            int read;

            InputStream input = originalZipFile.getInputStream(entry);

            CipherOutputStream cos = new CipherOutputStream(newZipFile, cipher);

            while((read = input.read(buffer)) != -1){
                cos.write(buffer, 0, read);
            }
            input.close();
            cos.close();
            newZipFile.closeEntry();

        }


    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RSA can only be used to encrypt relatively tiny amounts of data, less the size in bytes of the RSA modulus. When you execute `cos.close()`, the wrapped cipher object has its `doFinal()` method called which generates an `IllegalBlockSizeException` which is silently swallowed by `CipherOutputStream`. However, since no data made it through the cipher object the `ZipOutputStream` is messed up, so it throws an exception upon closure.

You can't use RSA the way you are trying to.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I just read that the encrypted pease of data should be smaller in size than the key. So what is the size of the key in bytes exactly, because it seems that 1024 for the `BUFFER_SIZE` is too much. What steps should I do to solve the problem.

Comment: I tried with different buffer sizes, and different file sizes, but I still get the same error. But with different numbers in  the invalid entry size, of course.

Comment: Should the file size by a multiple of the key size ? Meaning fileSize = n * keySize

Comment: I found out that for a 1024 bit key the length of the data for encryption should not be longer than 117, but even with that buffer size, it still doesn't work

Comment: You missed my point. You can't use RSA. RSA with a 1024-bit key can only encrypt 117 bytes in total. Your entire zip file would have to be <= 117 bytes in length.

Comment: Don't worry I fixed it. Thanks fot the help though , it really helped me :)